# Group by user id in Model relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two models: Report and User. This is what I have in my User model

```
public function userReport() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report', 'user_id','id');
}
```

And this is in Report model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

Controller

```
public function details( $item_id ){

    $report = Item::find($item_id)->report;
    return view('details', compact('report'));
}
```

In view

```
{!! $report->user->name !!}
```

In view I show all the users who are reported single Item .. which I query by `$item_id`.

The problem is that if same user is reported single item 1+ time I see this user 1+ time in the table on the page.

Is it possible to somehow grouped by user_id or count the user_id and show `User1 ( 4 time reported )` ...? Where should I group them?

Update: users table

```
id | username | password
```

reports table

```
report_id | id | user_id | date
```

item table

```
id | user_id | category | date_added | image
```

**Update2**: Image of records in db. Here user with `user_id=3` has reported `item_id=14` total of 14 times. User with `user_id=5` has reported same `item_id=14` total of 3 times. So I should see on page `user_id=3 ( 14 )` and `user_id=3 ( 3 )`. Instead I see 17 times `user_id=3`. Bellow are images

[image]

And on page

[image]

Comment: An report has many items?

Comment: Many items yes.

Answer (score 1):

There should be several ways how to solve your problem

One way is (your controller should look like)

```
public function details( $item_id ){    
    $report = Item::find($item_id)->report->unique('user_id');
    return view('details', compact('report'));
}
```

Second way should be to use `@foreach` in view and there check for unique values.

Third way should be to use `foreach` in controller and prepare unique data with calculated summarizes inside controller and then pass that prepared data to view.

Which soulution you want to use is just a matter of choice.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks but got `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()`

Comment: Now another error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$report`

Comment: Okay, now is acting like `groupBy` and showing user 1 time no matter how many records are there for this user. Is it possible to show counts also of records for that user?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this. Hope it helps

```
Report::where('item.id', $item_id)
    ->select('item.*','users.*',DB::raw('count(reports.report_id) as total'))
    ->join('item', 'item.id', '=', 'reports.id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'reports.user_id')
    ->groupBy('reports.report_id','reports.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This is showing only one user. If there is another user who is reported same item it doesn't showing it.

Comment: can you post your DB structure for this models. So that I can help you more

Comment: In table report can have multiple time same `user_id` to same `id` so when I load `id(=1)` and if there is 3 times `user_id(=1)` I want to show it once but counted ex: `user_1 ( 3 )`

Comment: you want to display the last reported time from the report for a specific user and item right?

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'item_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from items where item_id = 14 group by reports.user_id order by COUNT(user_id) asc)`

Comment: just try this `with(['report',function($query){
        $query->groupBy('user_id');
    }])`

Comment: Now I've got this `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given`

Comment: This is work but is not what I needed. This is showing only one user twice. Should show me the user only once. Like it doesn't group them. In database user with id=3 has reported 14 times item with id=1. This means I want when I click on report_id = 1 to see on page `user_3 ( 14 )` not 14 times user_3

Comment: Showing only one user. What if 2 different users are reported this item? It doesn't show the second user.

Comment: Okay. I will wait. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer have a look on it and try this one

Comment: @JayminPanchai I have updated my question. Please check it.